# ImportError: cannot import name np_utils in AWS Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I run my .ipynb file in AWS Sagemaker.

Unlike Colab, we need to install the dependencies separately in Sagemaker.

While pip installing tensorflow,I got error like **ImportError: cannot import name np_utils**.

After that I installed that too by **!pip install np_utils**
Then also I face similar error.

If this is in local system, it may be due to system configuration. Since its in Sagemaker,I am not sure about how to proceed futher.

Comment: Please include full error messages

Comment: The issue has been solved by using the kernel conda_tensorflow_p36. By using this kernel we need not pip install the dependencies.